# Presto Error : Response does not contain a JSON value

Tags: presto

I am trying to run Presto on Cloudera VM image and get the following error with both metadata and data queries.
Error running command: Response does not contain a JSON value

Did anyone see this. Any idea on how to fix it.
thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the exact versions of Cloudera and Hadoop you are using?  There are reports of incompatibilities and the team has been coding to CDH4.

Comment: Can you check `server.log` on the coordinator and workers for anything that might indicate the problem? Feel free to post the entire thing using a paste service like https://gist.github.com.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the problem. Finally I realized changed http-server.http.port to 8000 in presto server config.properties but forgot to change port to 8000 on cli command. In this scenario server.log won't contain any logs.

I think maybe it's better to emphasize that the cli start command should use the same port as configured in config.properties of presto-server on cli page http://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/cli.html